# Summarizing "reduce" in Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 5

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am currently reading "Eloquent Javascript" by Marijn Haverbeke but having trouble understanding high order functions.

In "Summarizing with reduce" of Chapter 5, he writes the following code:

```
function characterCount(script) {
  return script.ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {
    return count + (to - from);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(SCRIPTS.reduce((a, b) => {
  return characterCount(a) < characterCount(b) ? b : a;
}));
```

Sample of `SCRIPTS`:

```
var SCRIPTS = [
  {
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Caucasian Albanian",
    ranges: [[66864, 66916], [66927, 66928]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 420,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_Albanian_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahom",
    ranges: [[71424, 71450], [71453, 71468], [71472, 71488]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1250,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahom_alphabet"
  }
]
```

I'm having difficulty trying to wrap my head around this. Can anybody help by explaining this line by line, if that's not too much trouble? Would really appreciate all the help!

Thanks!

---

```js
var SCRIPTS = [
  {
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Caucasian Albanian",
    ranges: [[66864, 66916], [66927, 66928]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 420,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_Albanian_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahom",
    ranges: [[71424, 71450], [71453, 71468], [71472, 71488]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1250,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahom_alphabet"
  }
]

function characterCount(script) {
  return script.ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {
    return count + (to - from);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(SCRIPTS.reduce((a, b) => {
  return characterCount(a) < characterCount(b) ? b : a;
}));
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of `SCRIPTS`, please?

Comment: `reduce` works on `Array`s like so:
`arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])`.
More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @iAmOren Hi! Thanks for responding. Here's a direct link to the JS file [SCRIPTS](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/scripts.js)

Comment: Thank you.
I meant the object.
I'll edit your question to include part of it.

Comment: Created snippet from sample and code - seems to return the first `SCRIPTS` array's object...

Comment: Sure!
What is the expected output?  If you run the snippet, it will return the first `SCRIPTS` array's object...

Comment: I seems to return the biggest sum of ranges...
"Adlam" is 87,
"Caucasian Albanian" is 53, and
"Ahom" is 57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) works on `Array`s like so:
`arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])`.

`SCRIPTS.reduce` return the object with the largest `characterCount`.

`function characterCount` returns `script.ranges.reduce`, which returns the sum of difference of ranges of object sent by `SCRIPTS.reduce`.
As `currentValue`, it "creates" an `Array` from `ranges` and gives names: `from` and `to`, and adds their difference to `count` which is initialized to zero (`0`).

I hope this is helpful and that I didn't miss anything.
See the snippet I've added in an edit to the question.

---

Transforming:

```
function characterCount(script) {
  return script.ranges.reduce((count, [from, to]) => {
    return count + (to - from);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(SCRIPTS.reduce((a, b) => {
  return characterCount(a) < characterCount(b) ? b : a;
}));
```

to use names like in `Array.reduce`'s definition, and spread across more lines in an attempt at readability:

```
function characterCount(script) {
  return
    script.ranges.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        return
          accumulator + (currentValue[1] - currentValue[0]);
      }, 0
    );
}

console.log(
  SCRIPTS.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return
        characterCount(accumulator) < characterCount(currentValue)
          ? currentValue
          : accumulator;
    }
  )
);
```

Also, `characterCount(a) < characterCount(b) ? b : a` is equal to:

```
if(characterCount(a) < characterCount(b)) b;
else                                      a;
```

and is a [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a bit confused about how param (a, b) are used here. I understand that after the console.log() line, the function will now show characterCount(a). What's the value of "a" in this case? Thanks again! I appreciate all your answers.@iAmOren

Comment: I've added to the answer a "tranformation" to names used in definition.
`currentValue` in `characterCount` function was read as an array to get names (was `[from, to]` used in `to - from`, is `currentValue` used in `currentValue[1]` and `currentValue[0]` : [0]==from, [1]==to...
I hope this further clears things up!